# How to find Select Option text start with

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box like below,

```
<select id="fruit">
    <option value="0">--select--</option>
    <option value="1">apple</option>
    <option value="2">pineapple</option>
    <option value="3">orange</option>
<select>
```

I need to check any of its text start with "p" something like this

```
 if(jQuery('#fruit option[text^="p"]').length){
  //  something to do
    }
```

I know if its value we can get something like,

```
if(jQuery('#fruit option[value^="p"]').length){
      //  something to do
        }
```

But for text its not working. Im not getting what I missed here also checked through out the forum not find any thing close to this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `text` is not an attribute, you cannot match it. You will have to do this the hard way, [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is your best bet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use  `filter()` for that

```
$("#fruit option").filter(function() { return $(this).text().indexOf("p") === 0; })
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/98/)

**Edit**

[**Updated demo with case sensitive filtering**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/99/)

Comment: Is there any option to avoid case sensitive. Means I have to check both Upper case and lowercase, right now it only check lower case